# Remove certain symbol from insert

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I would like to remove the symbol `°` from a field that's to be inserted into my database. Now I already have `Format::Strip_tags` on my field.

How can I get the value `°` from the field to be changed with `#`? The symbol `°` gives error and when I check my MYSQL database, I get this:

Connection: utf8_general_ci

Database: latin1_swedish_ci

Server: latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: It says it's an invalid string input. DB Error 1366.

Comment: Thankyou. Precision is important when describing a problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP:

```
str_replace('°', '#', $yourString)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer; the OP's MySQL server is not UTF-8 and won't accept the degree-char input.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) funciton:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable
    SELECT REPLACE(YourValue, '°', '#')
    ...
```